# How to add a copyright symbol in reason-react component?

Tags: unicode, html-entities, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I’m new to reason-react. I’m trying to put a copyright symbol in a react-reason component. I've tried

```
<span >(ReasonReact.stringToElement("&copy;"))</span>
```

but this doesn’t give me the © symbol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's also possible, and usually simpler, to just use the unicode character:

```ml
let copy = ReasonReact.stringToElement({js|\u00a9|js});

// Since ReasonReact 0.7.0 you can use
let copy = React.string({js|\u00a9|js});
```

Or even shorter:

```ml
let copy = [%raw {|'\u00a9'|}];
```

It's also possible to use unicode characters directly, as long as the whole toolchain supports it properly:

```
let copy = React.string({js|©|js});
```

Then for either of these you can now do:

```jsx
<span> {copy} </span>
```

Answer (score 22):

Simply put: `&copy;`
if you don't put ; it will not work

Answer (score 15):

If you're doing HTML entities like that you have to use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute like so:

```
<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ "__html": "&copy;" }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the use the copy symbol all you have to to is write this ' © '

make sure to write it exactly like that.